# Can I find the function of X and Y that best predicts the value of Z given a few data triplets?

Tags: regression

Given the following data points

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18.23 | 3 | 80 |
| 42.2 | 5.5 | 600 |
| 377.30 | 52.04 | 900 |
| 6835.86 | 646.91 | 17 000 |
| 250 | 20 | ? |

Can I find the function of X and Y that best predicts the value of Z?

Is this a surface fitting problem?

Comment: `Can I find the function of X and Y that best predicts the value of Z?` I don't know, can you? What are these columns, give us some context.

Comment: Lol someone's having a bad day. Someone competent gave me a nice answer over here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686133/can-i-find-the-function-of-x-and-y-that-best-predicts-the-value-of-z-given-a-few/4686235#4686235